# jquery array not looping through all elements

Tags: jquery

I am creating an array of text values from a group of dynamically generated textareas.

I put an alert statement in the loop to see if it was working, and it's only alerting the first textarea that it encounters but none of the rest.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var textArray = [];

$('[name=txtObjective]').each(function (i) {
     alert($(this).val());
     textArray.push(i.val());
});
```

And here is what my textareas look like:

```
 <textarea name='txtObjective' class='objectives'>this is some text</textarea>
 <textarea name='txtObjective' class='objectives'>this is some more text</textarea>
 <textarea name='txtObjective' class='objectives'>this is even some more text</textarea>
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `$('textarea[name=txtObjective]').each(function (i) {` change this way and try

Comment: Why you don't use class names instead of names? and yes add textarea into your selector

Comment: look for error on console.

Comment: @ali:Not neccessary , it should work with any attr of the elements.

Comment: You need to iterate through class not name.

Comment: @dreamweiver i know. it was just a suggestion. better to use classes.

Comment: Fenil Shah: Thats not a neccessary , that you use classname always, it willwork any attributes of the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
$('[name=txtObjective]').each(function (i) {
     textArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

In your code, `i` is an index (0,1,2) which makes no sense to try and push into your array. `.each()` has two parameters, an index and a value, and you were trying to use the value of the index which of course doesn't work. By using `$(this).val()` you can push the value of the textarea into your array.

Comment: _In your code, i is an index (0,1,2) which makes no sense to try and push onto your array._  **No, It wouldn't push the index as `i.val()` would have thrown an error**.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are getting an error when executing `textArray.push(i.val());`.. The first arg in `.each` is index which is an number and applying `.val` would throw an error and breaks out of the loop.

Either use the second arg which is the element or use `this`.

Change `textArray.push(i.val());` to `textArray.push($(this).val());`

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your textareas like so :

```
<textarea name='txtObjective[]' class='objectives'>
```

And use :

```
$('textarea.objectives').each(function(i){
    //your code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have got error on console - `Object 0 has no method 'val'`

```
$('[name=txtObjective]').each(function (i) {
     alert($(this).val());
     textArray.push($(this).val()); // <<-- use $(this) here instead of i
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/j8JgX/